# Mouseover/leave problem

Tags: javascript, html, mouseleave, mouseenter

I have a `span` that includes an anchor and a `span`. Example below

```
<span id="x"><a id="a_in" href="">link</a><span id="x_in">x</span></span>
```

Now I am attaching a `mousenter` / `mouseleave` event on the `span` with `id="x"`. When I mouse over the the `span id="x"` it triggers the `mousenter` / `mouseleave` that's fine. The problem is when I `mouseover` the `span id="x_1"` inside the parent `span` mouseleave gets triggered.

I want `mousenter` / `mouseleave` to be triggered only when I `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` the parent.

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: i think the second reference to `span id="x"` is actually `span id="x_in"`

Comment: For me the when i mouseover the `span id="x_in"` the `mouseleave` doesn't get triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...thank you guys. The prob was on a new div that I was showing on the mouseenter which overlapped my SPAN X and triggered mouseleave.

Also...

> MooTools features mouseenter and
>   mouseleave because mouseover/mouseout
>   sometimes just does not work as
>   expected. Mouseenter only fires once
>   you enter the element and does not
>   fire again if your mouse crosses over
>   children of the element.

...so pretty much it does what you guys are suggesting and it works fine.
http://demos.mootools.net/Mouseenter

Just in case someone is looking for how to stop propagation using mootools...

$('myelement').addEvent('click', function (e) {
            var event = e || window.event;
            if (event.stopPropagation) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                event.cancelBubble = true;
            }
        });

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**short answer:** you can't avoid this, 
but you can determine that the mouseleave/enter only happens on the parent

```
function mouseleaveOrEnterHandler(e){
   e = e || window.event;
   var target = e.target || e.which;
   if(target.id=='x') {
      //do something here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be specific in what event you want to fire on what element. If your using jQuery: `$("span#x").hover(function() { 
  //action logic for mouse enter
}, function() { 
  //action logic for mouse leave
});`

Answer (score 0):

you need `cancelBubble()` and `stopPropagation()`.

See here: http://www.thedutchguy.com/article/javascript-prevent-event-bubbling-parent-child-when-fired.html

and also here: http://www.openjs.com/articles/prevent_default_action/